# Static storage union and named members initialization in C language

Tags: c, initialization, language-lawyer, union, c99

chapter 6.7.8.10 of ISO/IEC C9899:1999 standard describes how unions with static storage duration are initialized:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned)    zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized    (recursively) according to these rules;
> - **if it is a union, the first    named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.**

let's assume that we have following code, where actually second member of the union has greater memory footprint than first member of the union:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
    uint32_t c; 
    uint32_t d;
} my_structure_t;

typedef union
{
    uint8_t *first_member;
    my_structure_t later_member;  
} my_union_t;

static my_union_t data;
```

Is it somewhere in C standard defined how memory area occupied by  `later_member` is going to be initialized ? Because below statements I suspect that this is implementation defined behavior, however I need confirmation and at least links to some gcc, clang, ghs documentation, where it's described.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1311.pdf

> Then comes DR_016 which (in question 2) starts of with:  This one is
>   relevant only for hardware on which either null pointer or floating
>   point  zero is  /not/  represented as all zero bits.
>   It deals with
>
> `union { char *p; int i; } x;`
>
> and then states:
>
> If the null pointer is
>   represented as, say, 0x80000000, then there is no way to  implicitly
>   initialize this object.  Either the p member contains the null
>   pointer, or  the i member contains 0, but not both.  So the behavior
>   of this translation unit is  undefined.  This is a bad state of
>   affairs. I assume it was not the Committee's  intention to prohibit a
>   large class of implicitly initialized unions; this would render  a
>   great deal of existing code nonconforming.

Question is mainly targeted to C99 standard, however comparisons with other C standards are more than welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because only the first named member of a `union` is initialized, any additional remaining bytes belonging to other members remain uninitialized and have **indeterminate values**, and any trailing padding is set to 0.

The same clause you mentioned above is worded slightly differently in C11:

> if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, **and any padding is initialized to zero bits;**

Since a `union` can only contain one member at a time, it is not a problem that bytes corresponding to other members are not set, since the standard says you shouldn't read them anyway.

Comment: *"since the standard says you shouldn't read them anyway."* Where is that stated in standard? Standard explicitly allows type punning with unions.

Comment: @user694733 Further up in the same paragraph, C17 6.7.9 §10. `If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate.` In case of C11/C17, the first member is initialized and the rest of the union is regarded as padding and set to zero. In C90/C99 the rest of the union takes indeterminate values (not specified). If you read another member through type punning, and it is small enough to be covered by the initial member, then no problem. If the other member is larger than the initial, you end up reading indeterminate values.

Comment: The other relevant section of the standard would be C17 6.2.6.1 §6 `If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate. The value of a structure or union object is never a trap representation, even though the value of a member of the structure or union object may be a trap representation.` Meaning UB on systems with trap representations for the involved types.

Comment: And C17 6.2.6.1 §7 `When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.`

Comment: @Lundin I know. I only pointed that out because answer can interpreted to say that these uninitialized members are not really a problem because you can *never* type pun them. Paragraph as it stands currently in the answer is ambiguous.

Comment: @Lundin _.. and **the rest of the union is regarded as padding**.._. Can you share any reference to support this statement?

Comment: @H.S. It is the only sensible interpretation of the part cited in the answer. That is, if we have `union { uint8_t u8; uint16_t u16; } u = {0xAA}` then the only sensible outcome would be an initialization to `0xAA00`, where the byte after `u8` is regarded as padding during initialization.

Comment: @Lundin The C11 Standard#6.7.2.1p17 very specifically mentions about union padding - `There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.` There may be padding at the end of union for the alignment purpose. Typically, the `0` initialized static data goes in .bss and due to which the other bytes filled with zero, but the standard do not mention anything about the segments and these are architecture/platform specific. Hence, better to not to make any assumption about the byte after `u8`.

Comment: Padding that exists in a union because it is padding associated with an object named in the union is not defined anywhere to be a part of the union's own padding. F.ex. `struct s { int i; char c; }` likely has padding at the end whereas `union u { int i; struct s s; }` has no padding; `union u { double d; char c[sizeof (double+1)]; }` has padding.

Comment: Also, there is another sensible interpretation based on 6.2.6.1: `When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.` in the example @Lundin provided, the additional bytes in u16 are "bytes of object representation that do not correspond to that member", not padding bytes.

Comment: Finally -- and this is admittedly not normative -- the C17 draft footnote 97 states `If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation.` -- so it is at least not the intent of the standard to say you shouldn't read the "unset" members.

Answer (score 1):

As per the C99 Standard, the union object that has static storage duration and is not initialized explicitly, the compiler should initialize the first named member (recursively)<sup>1)</sup>. Hence, you should not make any assumption about the value of members other than first member, if their size is bigger than the first named member of union, because as per standard the compiler will only initialize first named member of union and the left over bytes of the members bigger than first named member reside uninitialized.

C Standards do not mention anything about the Data segment (initialized/uninitialized), Stack, Heap etc. These all are architecture/platform specific. For the object initialization (in case of static storage duration), the C Standards only specify what to be initialize to `0`/`NULL` and what not and it does not specify which storage duration object go in which segment. The Standard specifications are for compilers and a good compiler is expected to follow them. Typically, the `0` initialized static data goes in `.BSS` (Block Started by Symbol), non `0` initialized data goes in `.DATA` (Data Segment). So, you may find `later_member` structure (which is the second member of union `my_union_t` ) members value `0` but that may not always be the case.

---

The C11 Standard includes the specification about padding bytes of union (per 6.7.9p10) [emphasis added]:

> 10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
> ......
>
> ......
>
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any **padding is initialized to zero bits**;

Answer (score -1):

In theory only the pointer to be zeroed, but usually the whole section .bss is zeroed. To make sure just change the order of the members.

Comment: What's `.bss` and how is it relevant here?